# Переназначение ключей массива

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

```
// php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($fruits);
echo "</pre>";

// html
Array
(
[4] => "11"
[5] => "21"
[0] => "31"
[1] => "41"
[2] => "51"
[6] => "61"
[3] => "71"
)
```

Был массив, я его упорядочил функцией `asort()`, что привело к построению по порядку значений у ключей. Но при этом сами ключи теперь построены в беспорядочном виде. соответственно вопрос. Подскажите, как назначить данному массиву новые ключи, чтобы было что-то вроде:

```
// php
функция_которую_я_не_нашел_в мануале($fruits);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($fruits);
echo "</pre>";

// html
Array
(
[0] => "11"
[1] => "21"
[2] => "31"
[3] => "41"
[4] => "51"
[5] => "61"
[6] => "71"
)
```

Comment: Т.е. нужно просто отсортировать массив без сохранения ключей?) `array(5 => 15, 2 => 3) --> array(0 => 3, 1 => 15)`

Comment: да. чтобы первый ключ был 0, второй 1... и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)

Если значения совпадают и перезаписываются (не могу сейчас проверить), тогда проще так

```
$arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr as $v)
  $arr2 []= $v;
```

Comment: немного по другому поступил, перебором назначил ключи значения нового массива. а потом уже asort()